# What Transponder code to use flying between Oakland and Hawaii?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, squawk-codes

Where to find the appropriate Transponder code for crossing the Pacific?

Comment: I read this question as *"what is a transponder code?"*

Comment: Do you want to attempt a VFR fly over the pacific?

Comment: Flying IFR, or VFR?

Comment: Did you find other *route-specific* squawk codes? It helps to mention the reason for asking so the answers don't have to guess, i.e. *why* Oakland–Hawaii specifically? It's *much* better to ask about the general topic if you don't know much about it. See also, [How do I ask a good question?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): *"If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer."*

Answer (score 4):

Whichever code is assigned to the individual flight by ATC. There isn't a fixed code to use for any one specific route. You might want to see: [How does ATC know if you have been assigned a squawk or not?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/30413/)

Answer (score 2):

IFR flights outside radar coverage will typically be told to squawk 2000, in contrast with VFR flights that will be squawking 7000 or 1200. Upon reaching radar coverage again, they will be given a new discrete code.

Comment: These are not, however, pacific specific (how poetic).

Comment: It's mostly to have them broadcasting for TCAS purposes.

Comment: @JohnK ... without conflicting with any discrete code that might already be in use on any side of the non-radar area. It also serves as a visible reminder to the receiving side that the aircraft needs a discrete code once it shows up on their scope.